# Relation between SparkSession command an a slave worker in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have two master workers running with high availability with ZooKeeper, in standalone mode. I need to run three tasks in django several times with spark, and two of them (two endpoints) must be executed simultaneously. After I started the two master workers (first one as leader and second in stand by), my goal is when one of the task is called, an slave should execute the task, and after that, the slave will be release, the same thing with the other task.

After I ran master worker and execute this part in my endpoint to start the process of the task:

```
spark=SparkSession \
  .builder \
  .master("spark://"+SPARK_WORKERS) \
  .appName('word_cloud') \
  .config("spark.executor.memory", '2g') \
  .config('spark.executor.cores', '2') \
  .config('spark.cores.max', '2') \
  .config("spark.driver.memory",'2g') \
  .getOrCreate()

sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)
tweetsRDD=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(tweetsList)
df = sqlContext.read.json(tweetsRDD)
```

I receive this error:

```
Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

According to this answer, I need to start the slave worker:

`./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://host:port --cores 2 --memory 2g # as an example`

So after that, it worked good.

**My Question is**

When `SparkSession` command is executed, it makes a requests with the resources specified (memory, cores...), then the master assign the task to an active slave that need to be started with the same resources (or more)? so, It needs to happend this always like that?

I have this basic doubt because I can't understand, Why If an slave worker is running with cores and memory, Spark Session command need to be set with resources also, Is this process (the assigment of a task with specified resources, to an slave worker with the same or more resources) not be happend automatically by spark?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: unless you have a cluster manager (kubernetes, YARN, etc), you have to manage the cluster. and `spark://` means you have to manage the cluster by yourself (standalone). https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html

Comment: @DynoFu certainly that make sense. So in that context, could be a suggested way, If at the start of each endpoint, a new slave is started to take of the request and at the end the worker will be stopped? I appreciate your help

Comment: i think you should start a long running spark cluster when your server start, and  in the request handler submit job to it, just getOrCreate() which will reuse the existing cluster. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.Builder.getOrCreate